# wtforms SelectMultipleField returning only 1 selected value

Tags: flask-wtforms

im following this tutorial to implement a multi checkbox field in flask with jinja

https://gist.github.com/doobeh/4668212

It works for the most part but when I go to access the value in my code (products is the field where I used the multicheckbox) like

```
class CreateBoardForm(Form):
    products = MultiCheckboxField(
        'Select Products:',
        coerce=int,
        choices=[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')])

......


if request.method == 'POST':
    products=request.form['products']
    print name, description, tags
    print "Selected products:", products
```

When I print selected products I only see one value being selected. When I printed the forms object I see this python data structure `ImmutableMultiDict([('products', u'1'), ('products', u'3')])`

Im not sure how to get all the values for the 'products' key

Comment: @sakibi have you ever been able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use the `getlist` method in order to return a list of other choices.

```
request.form.getlist('products')
```